# Using GYP for generating Visual Studio projects

Tags: node-gyp, gyp

I am trying to generate VS project with gyp for [minidump_writer_file_unittest.cc present here](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/client/minidump_file_writer_unittest.cc). The way to compile this test on linux machines is given in the same link on line 33.

Now, this test depends upon header files present in the parent directory of where this file is present. How do I include these header files in my project?

Currently, my gyp file looks like this:

```
{
    'targets': [
      {
        'target_name': 'unittest',
        'type': 'executable',
        'sources': [
           'minidump_file_writer.h',
           'minidump_file_writer.cc',
           'minidump_file_writer-inl.h',
           'minidump_file_writer_unittest.cc',
        ]
        'include_dirs': [
               '..',
            ],
      }
    ]
}
```

And I run this file with:

```
src\tools\gyp\gyp.bat  --no-circular-check src\client\unittest_.gyp
```